# Amazon ECS container showing strange CPU usage after deployment

Tags: cpu-usage, amazon-ecs

I'll preface this by saying I'm fairly new to working with AWS.

Yesterday I deployed a new version of one of our services to our test environment.
Most people are on holidays at the moment, so there isn't a lot of usage of this particular container.
The new version I deployed had some changes to logger configuration, the logger uses a new encoder that outputs logstash json format logs. So no business logic changes.
I deployed the service and it timed out because the health check failed twice (trying to run two instances).
I added 30 seconds to the wait time to see if it would deploy, it hung for a long time with CPU at 100%, but eventually stabilised.
However, once it stabilised, the CPU was running between 0% and 10% and seemed quite erratic. I let it run for a while then decided to revert to the previous image and investigate what the issue might be.
When I reverted to the older image the same thing happened. Spiked at 100% for a while, then stabilised, with the CPU active with around 10% load.
I left it over night, but it's still the same this morning.
What can the issue be?  The old image worked fine before I deployed the new one.

We're using ECS, running Tasks.
I should note that the service is working as expected, I can query the API's and I get results quickly.
This is what the health graphs looked like this morning:
[image: container health graphs CPU and Memory]

The flat part of the graph is using the original task, the first spike is deploying the new task, and the second spike is re-deploying the original task.
What could be the issue here?

Here is the same graph over a longer time period:
[image: graph CPU and Memory 1 week]

Answer (score 0):

We are facing similar issue with our ECS service where average CPU spikes up to 20-30% for around 1 hour after the deployment succeeds and same trend for memory as you have shown, and then it stabilises around 5% post ~1 hour. Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: We weren't I'm afraid, just like you said, it seemed to stabilise after an hour or so. Never got to the bottom of it. It did stop happening after a while, and hasn't happened much recently. So I'm wondering if it's something going on with the 'magic' in the background. In any case, I haven't given it much thought since I've had other priorities I needed to focus on.

Comment: Also, FYI - this should probably be a comment on my question, rather than an answer. :-)

Comment: Hasn't stopped happening for us apparently, will need to go to the bottom of it..Alas! 

PS: don't have enough repo points to comment so had to resort to answer :/

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/574493)